# QPixmap is not shown when run application in Qt

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qlabel, qpixmap, qt-resource

Qt Designer allows me to add a *.png* file as a `QLabel`'s pixmap, But it's only visible there, and not when running the app, and there are no errors.

This occurs when the picture is already included in a *.qrc* file, but loaded as a file and not as a resource (button "Choose Resource..." in the Property Editor)

Comment: I checked my ui_mainwindow.h file.
When I use absolute path it contains this function call:      setPixmap(QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8("../images/profile.png")));
 and when I use resource path it has this call: setPixmap(QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8(":/profile")));
where "profile" is a correct alias.
The "../images/profile.png" address is actually right, but only for a file in the "project_name/src/game" or some other "src/" folder, and the project is placed in "project_name/qt".

Comment: It's very obscure what file and how is writing down this address, because, most likely, it wasn't the file from the folder with .pro file or from the build folder.
And I think a proper behavior would be just add __full__ path.

Comment: Also, when I copied this "profile.png" file to nonproject folder and renamed it. Qt Designer Dialog window declined to show this file before restarting Qt Creator, that's why I thought it's impossible to add .png files from Qt Designer at first.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `setPixmap(QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8("../images/profile.png"))); ` is a relative path not an absolute one. And if it did not load my expectation is your current working directory when running in the debugger (or however you are running it) is not the folder that you expected it to be.

Comment: `setPixmap(QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8(":/profile"))); ` without the `.png` extension?

Comment: yes, "profile" is an alias.
I suppose the problem is ui compiler writes down the address to the image for .ui file, instead of ui_***.h file. Or maybe uic have some certain expectation, where the image has to be, regardless to .ui file address. I see no other possible reason.

Comment: Designer uses a path that is relative to the .ui file, which seems perfectly reasonable. An absolute path would make no sense at all, since it would likely only ever work on the development machine. If you don't use the resource system, it's your responsibility to ensure that the images are installed to the correct (relative) location on every client machine.

Comment: @ekhumoro but it should add the address relative to ui_***.h then, right, because it's the file that is opening the image?

Comment: @MaxCury Not necessarily, because the .ui file might be loaded at runtime. If you want custom handling of the path, you could [define a pixmap function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-customizing-forms.html). But why not just use the resource system?

Answer (score 0):

The problem can usually be solved if you add this file to .qrc and use resource path with a prefix you made.

This problem can occur when the picture is in the same project folder, even if it is  added to .qrc, because Qt will shorten it's path in ui_filename.h and may do it incorrectly. Thus using file path instead of its alias or resource path is more insecure, Qt Designer will even show it properly, but you will not see it, while running, when ui_filename.h file will be used.

Summary: don't trust Qt Designer, just add everything to .qrc, especially if it is some exotic data format. You can try to open any other file from Designer->Property Editor->QLabel->pixmap->Choose File and see the list of available formats to use in the right bottom corner.
For me it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M1Le.png